# Prevent anyone from executing your web service?

Tags: web-services

I've got a webservice which is executed through javascript (jquery) to retrieve data from the database. I would like to make sure that only my web pages can execute those web methods (ie I don't want people to execute those web methods directly - they could find out the url by looking at the source code of the javascript for example).
What I'm planning to do is add a 'Key' parameter to all the webmethods. The key will be stored in the web pages in a hidden field and the value will be set dynamically by the web server when the web page is requested. The key value will only be valid for, say, 5 minutes. This way, when a webmethod needs to be executed, javascript will pass the key to the webmethod and the webmethod will check that the key is valid before doing whatever it needs to do.
If someone wants to execute the webmethods directly, they won't have the key which will make them unable to execute them.
What's your views on this? Is there a better solution? Do you forsee any problems with my solution?

MORE INFO: for what I'm doing, the visitors are not logged in so I can't use a session. I understand that if someone really wants to break this, they can parse the html code and get the value of the hidden field but they would have to do this regularly as the key will change every x minutes... which is of course possible but hopefully will be a pain for them.

EDIT: what I'm doing is a web application (as opposed to a web site). The data is retrieved through web methods (+jquery). I would like to prevent anyone from building their own web application using my data (which they could if they can execute the web methods). Obviously it would be a risk for them as I could change the web methods at any time.

I will probably just go for the referrer option. It's not perfect but it's easy to implement. I don't want to spend too much time on this as some of you said if someone really wants to break it, they'll find a solution anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: having a session and being logged in are not the same thing

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's nothing *technical* wrong with it, but your assumption that "they won't have the key which will make them unable to execute them" is incorrect, and thus the security of the whole thing is flawed.

It's very trivial to retrieve the value of a hidden field and use it to execute the method.

I'll save you a lot of time and frustration: If the user's browser can execute the method, a determined user can. You're not going to be able to stop that.

With that said, any more information on *why* you're attempting to do this? What's the context? Perhaps there's something else that would accomplish your goal here that we could suggest if we knew more :)

EDIT: Not a whole lot more info there, but I'll run with it. Your solution isn't really going to increase the security at all and is going to create a headache for you in maintenance and bugs. It will also create a headache for your users in that they would then have an 'invisible' time limit in which to perform actions on pages. With what you've told us so far, I'd say you're better off just doing nothing.

What kind of methods are you trying to protect here? Why are you trying to protect them?

ND

Answer (score 3):

> MORE INFO: for what I'm doing, the visitors are not logged in so I can't use a session.

If you are sending a client a key that they will send back every time they want to use a service, you are in effect creating a session.  The key you are passing back and forth is functionally no different than a cookie (expect that it will be passed back only on certain requests.)  Might as well just save the trouble and set a temporary cookie that will expire in 5 minutes.  Add a little server side check for expired cookies and you'll have probably the best you can get.

Answer (score 2):

You may already have such a key, if you're using a language or framework that sets a session id. Send that with the Ajax call. (Note that such a session lasts a bit longer than five minutes, but note also it's what you're using to keep state for the users regular HTPP gets and posts.)

Comment: Almost. Match that sessionid to an IP you keep internally and you've got a fairly strong (but certainly not bulletproof) way to prevent someone grabbing and using the sessionkey.

Answer (score 0):

What's to stop someone requesting a webpage, parsing the results to pull out the key and then calling the webservice with that?

You could check the referrer header to check the call is coming from one of your pages, but that is also easy to spoof.

The only way I can see to solve this is to require authentication. If your webpages that call the webservice require the user to be logged in then you can check the that they're logged in when they call the webservice. This doesn't stop other pages from using your webservice, but it does let you track usage more and with some rate limiting you should be able to prevent abuse of your service.

If you really don't want to risk your webservice being abused then don't make it public. That's the only failsafe solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you generate a key valid from 12.00 to 12.05. At 12.04 i open the page, read it with calm, and at 12.06 i trigger action which use your web service. I'll be blocked from doing so even i'm a legit visitor.

I would suggest to restrain access to web services by http referrer (allow only those from your domain and null referrers) and/or require user authentication for calling methods.

Comment: http_referer is trivial to spoof

Comment: It's trivial to spoof but another site can't reuse his javascript since the normal clients will send not spoofed referers